# Php exec() function is not working on heroku with command nice

Tags: php, heroku

I am using the following lines of php code in my heroku php app, but these lines are not working :

```
$exec = "ps -p pid | grep pid.php";
$cmd='nice -n15 ' . php path . ' external.php ';
$cmd.=" > /dev/null 2>/dev/null & echo $!";
$out=array();
exec($cmd, $out);
```

Could you please suggest any other alternative of this or what mistake this code have?

Comment: Please define "not working" : do you get an error message ? where does it fail ? You can add these by editing your post

Comment: I have not get any error msg but code of external.php file is not running.

Comment: And what is "php path"?

Comment: php path = /app/php/bin/php       but code of external.php not running

Comment: @Aryan any news about this one?